# Question about iOS 14 navigation stack management (different from iOS 13)

Tags: ios, uikit

I've been testing our app on iOS and I've noticed a weird behaviour that happens on iOS 14, but it doesn't happen on iOS 13. It's regarding the navigation stack and how it works.

Say I have a navigation stack of [A, B, C], where C is of course the topmost view controller. I have a button in the C view controller which gets the navigation stack, removes C and then B, and finally it adds a new view controller D. Then I set the new stack to the navigation controller.

On iOS 13, the resulting stack is [A, D].
On iOS 14, the resulting stack is [C, A, D]. Somehow, it didn't let me remove the current view controller from the stack, but it did add to the bottom of the stack.

My only explanation has been that it has something to do with the new navigation history feature in iOS 14 (long hold on the Back button). Somehow this introduced some new constraints on the management of the navigation stack.

Hopefully someone can help me understand the new behaviour.

Comment: Although I can't comment on how exactly the behavior works, try using functions like popToViewController instead of specifically resetting the entire stack with functions like setViewControllers. Does this change anything? I am interested. Also iOS 14 is in beta so I would imagine theres still some kinks.

Comment: @SanzioAngeli Hello Sanzio. Amazingly, using popToViewController does seem to do its job. Going back to my example, popToViewController with viewController A as a parameter, I do get [A], not [C, A] as I used to get with setViewControllers. I think this points to a bug, since both methods used to work the same in iOS13, but as you've said, iOS 14 is still in beta. Thanks a lot for your idea :D.

Comment: Interesting. You should fill something but I don't know how to go about that.

Comment: You should file a bug report immediately. Apple will go final with iOS 14 very soon!

Comment: Someone else experienced this here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656524?login=true&page=1#628731022     I shared this SO link there

Comment: For me on iOS 14.2 setViewControllers works properly - except it reduces the retain count on one of the VCs, and crashes a few seconds later when the user pushes/pops a screen.

Answer (score 6):

I'm facing a similar issue in the latest iOS 14 as well - If I use `setViewControllers:animated:` on the `UINavigationController`, instead of replacing the nav stack entirely with the array of view controllers provided as an argument, it retains the current top most view controller, and pushes the new view controllers on top of it.

Basically, if your current view controller stack is:

```
[V1, V2, V3,... Vn]
```

and you use `setViewControllers:animated` with an argument of:

```
[X1, X2, X3,... Xn]
```

After the transition, your view controller stack will be:

```
[Vn, X1, X2, X3,... Xn]
```

This bug does not happen on iOS 13 and lower versions.

Comment: I am faced the same issue in existing my project after updating Xcode 12 GM release version.
do you have any solution for this issue in Xcode 12?

Comment: @MiguelA. This issue was resolved in Xcode 12 beta 7 and I haven't seen it since. Are you sure you're seeing this in the GM?

Comment: sure, I installed Xcode 12 GM version and I saw this issue, so I installed Xcode12 GM and 11.7 together. Temporarily am building app by 11.7 version  to solve it

Comment: @MiguelA. as far as I can tell this still happens if you check the stack BEFORE viewDidAppear. Anyway on viewDidAppear it looks fine. I would really love to find a workaround to make it work on viewDidLoad too..

Answer (score 3):

It appears this was indeed an early beta issue and has been fixed in iOS 14 beta 6 / Xcode 12 beta 6.

```swift
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: originalViewController)

navigationController.setViewControllers([replacementViewController], animated: true)
```

Inspecting the view controllers after calling `setViewControllers`

```swift
navigationController.viewControllers
```

Now yields the expected results `[replacementViewController]` *(matching the iOS 13 behavior)*.

Comment: I'm still having the issue on the beta 7 :/
Whether I use setViewControllers, popToRootViewContoller or popViewController the result is always the same when animated: the stack is mixed up.

Comment: The issue is still in Version 12.1 (12A7403)(Public).

Comment: Here what I did: before setting view controllers try to set empty array [] without animatio :) In my case it helped!


navigationController.setViewControllers([], animated: false)
navigationController.setViewControllers([replacementViewController], animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

I found what may be a simple workaround to this issue. If you are going to use setViewControllers to set a new array of VC's, first call setViewControllers with an empty array (UIViewController), then immediately setViewControllers again with your actual array.

One caveat of this is that the willShow navigationController delegate will get called and it's viewController argument will be unitialized. So you can first check to see if the viewControllers.count is 0 and if so exit the will show.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this kind of issue. On my case I got a navigation controller with only a view controller on its stack, say `[viewControllerA]`. And when doing:

```
navigationController.setViewController([viewControllerB], animated: true)
```

on iOS 14 the navigation stack becomes:

```
[viewControllerA, viewControllerB]
```

while on iOS 13 (and below) it becomes:

```
[viewControllerB]
```

Like you can see on the [Apple foruns thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656524) referred above by @Sanzio Angeli, this is caused by a different behaviour when `setViewControllers` is called with `true` on `animated` parameter.

That behaviour is not trivial and despite being describe in detail on the [method's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers), if you check its source you can read this comment:

> open func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController], animated: Bool) // **If animated is YES, then simulate a push or pop depending on whether the new top view controller was previously in the stack.**

**SOLUTION**:

a) Set `animated` parameter to `false`, calling:

```
navigationController.setViewController([viewControllerB], animated: false)
```

or

b) Simply set `viewControllers` this way (which is identical to previous call):

```
navigationController.viewControllers = [viewControllerB]
```